# How do I stop Jraid.sys driver file from stopping my windows 7 upgrade?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, 64-bit, upgrade

Running the Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor indicated there would be no problem with an upgrade from Vista 64 Ultimate Edition.

Setup starts just fine, the computer then reboots, and after reboot a message is shown:

"Windows cannot find the file jraid.sys", with error code 0xc0000359

I am left with the option to choose 'setup' or 'vista' to boot. Of course, the vista installation is still fine, so I can choose to boot into that, but does anyone know how to get past this error?

I located the file in the update location despite the message. I deleted the file, Windows goes further into the install process but then errored and rolled back.

From what I could find the Jraid.sys driver is for my FireWire ports that I don't use...

Answer (score 2):

jraid.sys is a driver for a JMicron chip, usually the JMB36X or JMB38X, used for RAID and/or for extra IDE and SATA ports.

Check on the website of the manufacturer of the motherboard for an updated driver for JMicron for Windows 7 (recommended), or directly [at JMicron](ftp://driver.jmicron.com.tw/).

Load it using the "Load driver" button during the installation of Windows 7. It will ask for the location of the driver, usually a USB key or a floppy disk.

[image]